# Storing downloaded image in Core Data causes errors

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm retrieving some JSON and storing it in an array. Then in a dispatch block, I go over the array and call a separate method to insert each array item into Core Data. Like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [unowned self] in
    for result in jsonCategoriesArray {
      if let category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext) as? Category {
        self.insertCategory(category, usingJSON: result)
      }
    }

    self.saveCoreDataContext()
    self.loadSavedCategories()
})
```

Here is the insert method:

```
private func insertCategory(category: Category, usingJSON json: JSON) {
  let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
  formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true

  category.id = (formatter.numberFromString(json["ID"].stringValue) as? NSDecimalNumber)!
  category.categoryID = (formatter.numberFromString(json["IDKategori"].stringValue) as? NSDecimalNumber)!
  category.title = json["KategoriBaslik"].stringValue
  category.subCategoryCount = (formatter.numberFromString(json["AltKategoriSayi"].stringValue) as? NSDecimalNumber)!

  guard let url = NSURL(string: json["KategoriResim"].stringValue) else {
    return
  }

  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let httpUrlResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpUrlResponse.statusCode == 200,
        let mimeType = response?.MIMEType where mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
        let data = data where error == nil
    else {
      print("Problem downloading the image of the category with id: \(category.id) and name: \(category.title)")
      return
  }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
      category.logo = data
      self.saveCoreDataContext()
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("CategoryUpdate", object: nil)
    }
  }.resume()
}
```

The only problem is that the image download with `NSURLSession` causes the following error multiple times:

```
2016-07-07 12:33:21.284 En Yakın[24040:1541295] CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x790995a0 <x-coredata:///Category/t045D239A-9032-4B07-B870-46AA156B1D9B15> (0x79099560) after it has been removed from its context.
```

The images are thumbnail's of approximately 8 KB in size that are stored as `Binary Data`. How should I handle this?

Comment: Are you sure that the managed object context you're using still exists when the network request finishes?

Comment: @TomHarrington How can I achieve that?